# IE throws ERROR TypeError: Invalid calling object. Works fine in other browsers

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, internet-explorer, angular7

The IE (irrespective of version) throws `ERROR TypeError: Invalid calling object` when tried to hit the api. On inspection found that the headers are slightly different than what are in Chrome browser.

```
{
   "url":"",
   "body":"",
   "reportProgress":false,
   "withCredentials":false,
   "responseType":"text",
   "method":"GET",
   "headers":{
      "normalizedNames":{
         "_t":"Map",
         "_i":{

         },
         "_s":0
      },
      "lazyUpdate":null
   },
   "params":{
      "updates":null,
      "cloneFrom":null,
      "encoder":{

      },
      "map":null
   },
   "urlWithParams":""
}
```

The above is the request sent via IE.

```
{
   "url":"",
   "body":"",
   "reportProgress":false,
   "withCredentials":false,
   "responseType":"text",
   "method":"GET",
   "headers":{
      "normalizedNames":{

      },
      "lazyUpdate":null
   },
   "params":{
      "updates":null,
      "cloneFrom":null,
      "encoder":{

      },
      "map":null
   },
   "urlWithParams":""
}
```

The above is the request sent via Chrome.

The api hit is a get type and returns the Json, which is success in chrome but IE throws in console.

Comment: Did you enable all polyfills for IE?

Comment: it's probably a code issue, not the request body that is the issue (assuming the error is on the browser, not the server) - the browser should be telling you which line of code threw the error, and, using the stack trace, you could narrow it down to a line of code that you wrote

Comment: @mbojko yes, i have enabled all the polyfills.

Comment: @JaromandaX I tried to narrow it down to understand the flow. The chrome goes inside the Observable.create method whereas, IE goes inside vendor js.

Comment: Try to set break point to debug your code and use F12 developer tools to check the detail error message. Besides, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).